# c++: runtime-linking shared object with host app, symbol table issue

Tags: c++, linker, visibility, dynamic-library

I have a `hostapp.cpp` that loads a `object.so` shared object at run-time, the shared object is compiled using only with the needed .h files from the host app but at run-time it needs to access those functions (present at the host app).

Compiling the host app with `-rdynamic` apparently solves this issue but it unnecessarily exposes the object to the full symbol table of the host app, even though it only needs to resolve a few of them.

How can I specify exactly what host-app symbols will be known by the shared object?

**Edit:** I'm building and running on GNU/Linux with the GNU toolchain.

Comment: I think you're looking for `__attribute__((visibility("default")))`

Comment: From your comment on the answer it seems to have satisfied you... if that is the case, please accept it; if not, please modify it or make another comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is under-specified: you never said what platform you are building for, what linker you use, etc.

Assuming you build for Linux, you can specify symbols to export from the main executable using one of the following methods:

1. If you are using gold (the GNU ELF linker), `--export-dynamic-symbol` will [do](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16369498/50617) what you need.
2. If you are using binutils linker, you can use linker version script to do the same ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/452955/50617)).
3. You can mark symbols to be exported with `__attribute__((visibility("default")))`, compile with `-fvisibility-hidden`, and link with `-rdynamic`. That should hide most of the symbols, but will not work well if you link in libraries which you can't recompile.

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to mention I'm under Linux and using the g++ toolchain