# constructor of shared library can not find symbol when dlopen loads it

Tags: constructor, dlopen

Here is the sample code of shared library:

```
#include <stdio.h>
extern void test();
__attribute__((used, constructor)) static void so_init()
{
    printf("loaded\n");
    test();
}
```

and here is the main:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
__attribute__((used)) void test()
{
    printf("test\n");
}
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    printf("hello world\n");
    return 0;
}
```

and the makefile:

```
so:a.c
        $(CC) -fPIC -c a.c -o a.o
        $(CC) a.o -fPIC -shared -o liba.so
test:m.c
        $(CC) -fPIC -c m.c -o m.o
        $(CC) m.o -fPIC -o test -L./ -la -Wl,-rpath,./
```

It works as I expect:

```
loaded
test
hello world
```

BUT, when I use dlopen to load that so, something goes wrong.
Now, main is:

```
__attribute__((used)) void test()
{
    printf("test\n");
}
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    printf("hello world\n");
    void* so = dlopen("./liba.so", RTLD_LAZY);
    printf("%p\n", so);
    dlclose(so);
    return 0;
}
```

and Makefile is:

```
so:a.c
        $(CC) -fPIC -c a.c -o a.o
        $(CC) a.o -fPIC -shared -o liba.so
test:m.c
        $(CC) -fPIC -c m.c -o m.o
        $(CC) m.o -fPIC -o test -ldl
```

and the result of running is:

```
hello world
loaded
./test: symbol lookup error: ./liba.so: undefined symbol: test
```

It seems dlopen calls function so_init, but function so_init can not find symbol: test which is at main.

So, focus on constructor, what's the difference between linked at compile time and load at run time?
Why dlopen can not find symbol?
How can I fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what's the difference between linked at compile time and load at run time?

By default, symbols from the main binary are *not* exported in its dynamic symbol table, *unless* they are referenced by a shared library participating in the link.

You can compare the output from `nm -D ./test | grep test` in the two cases. When linking `test` with `-la`, the `test()` symbol will appear in `nm -D` output. When linking without `-la`, the symbol will not appear (but will still be present in `nm ./test` output).

To *force* the symbol to be exported, you can use `-rdynamic` (exports *all* symbols) or `-Wl,--export-dynamic-symbol=test` if your linker supports it (related [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16369498/50617)).

P.S. Naming the binary `test` is not a great idea, because `/usr/bin/test` likely exists on your system as well.